# Javadoc - how to copy function description?

Tags: java, javadoc

I have two Java functions:

```
/**
* Do something with param
*/
public String doSomething(String param) {...};

/**
* ...
*/
public String doSomething(Integer param) {...};
```

How can I make the second function's description to show an exact copy of the first function?

Comment: Why don't you use copy and paste? In any way you have to adapt the parameter param.

Comment: @Roflcoptr, not if the overloaded params only differ in type, i.e. have the same name and description. And maybe the OP doesn't want to violate the DRY principle :-)

Comment: @peter-torok, exactly :)

Comment: Ok I see, I thought that two params with different types can't have the same description.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618185/how-can-a-methods-javadoc-be-copied-into-other-methods-javadoc

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Assuming copy and paste won't work for you, I believe the convention is to use the @see tag to refer to another method which will give greater detail.

In your example the doSomething(Integer param) would have an @see tag referring to the String version.

Wikipedia has some examples, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc

As does the oracle site for the javadoc tool http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#multiple@see

Answer (score 9):

The short answer is you can't. Customary is to make use of the `@see` directive or simply copy pasting.

If you are subclassing you can put the javadoc on the interface level instead to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 6):

As two methods with different type params can't have the same description. 
But for inherited method we can use same description.

### inherited method

For inherited method u can use

`{@inheritDoc}`

It copies the description from the overridden method.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to do that. You want the second one to *refer* to the first one. That's what @see is for. You never want to repeat documentation, for the same reason that your second method calls the first method instead of containing a copy of its code.

Comment: Copy-paste doc is not like copy-paste code? Avoid duplicate code/doc decreases maintenance time.

Answer (score 1):

Don't just use `{@see ...}`, which has a different meaning and has some problems (like not overriding inherited documentation).

A spartan `/** See: {@link ...}. */` is better.

However, best is to add a bit more text than just "See". Briefly describe the intent of this method and what is specific to it, and `{@link ...}` to a method which explains the full contract in detail. This is often done in the JDK and other libraries and is a good practice.

Eg:

```
/**
 * Does something very important.
 * For details see {@link #doSomething(Integer)}.
 */
```

or:

```
/**
 * Does something very important.
 * Equivalent to calling {@link #doSomething(Integer) doSomething(0)}.
 */
```