# Make sure method is executed, even if overriden

Tags: java, class, oop, hierarchy

Let's say I have an interface with some methods, like this:

```
interface Task {
    void before();
    void doStuff();
    void after();
}
```

Here I would implement part of it:

```
abstract class PoliteTask implements Task{

    @Override
    public void before() {
        System.out.println("Hey");
    }


    @Override
    public abstract void doStuff();


    @Override
    public void after() {
        System.out.println("Cya");
    }

}
```

Now I want to make sure that those `before()` and `after()` implementations are called in all extending classes.

Here we have a class that needs to init something in `before()`:

```
class ActualStuffTask extends PoliteTask {

    private int fancyNumber;


    @Override
    public void before() {
        // init some things
        fancyNumber = 42;
    }


    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("Look, a number: "+fancyNumber);
    }

}
```

Obviously, `ActualStuffTask` overrides `before()`, hence it does not say "Hey", only "Cya".

If I made the methods in `PoliteTask` `final`, this wouldn't happen, but then it's child classes could not override the methods.

Calling `super.before()` in the `ActualStuffTask` would work, but I want to have this effect guaranteed, regardless of child class implementation.

**The question is:**

What pattern should I use to have both parent implementation, and child implementation?

Comment: Have you considered just using `super.before()` in the child implementation?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel The API can't be dependent on the implementation of children.

Comment: Then you'll have to let go of the interface in your baseclass and name the methods differently. You can just make the ones to be implemented `abstract` and call them from the (differently named) ones in your baseclass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like to use abstract methods which you implement in the implementation classes.

```
abstract class PoliteTask implements Task{

    @Override
    public final void before() {
        System.out.println("Hey");
        doBefore();
    }

    protected abstract void doBefore();
    protected abstract void doAfter();

    @Override
    public abstract void doStuff();


    @Override
    public final void after() {
        System.out.println("Cya");
        doAfter();
    }

}

class ActualStuffTask extends PoliteTask {
    private int fancyNumber;

    @Override
    protected void doBefore() {
        // init some things
        fancyNumber = 42;
    }


    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("Look, a number: "+fancyNumber);
    }


    @Override
    protected void doAfter() {
        // something else
    }
}
```

Notice that the `Task` methods are `final`. They don't need to be. It depends how you are building your API.

Comment: Yeah, I use this too.. I just wanted to find a cleaner, universal solution - read: without changing of the abstract signature.

Comment: @MightyPork You don't have to change the signature. Sub classes of `PoliteTask` already have implemented it.

Comment: I guess this is the real answer. I'd like to keep the same names for the methods, but apparently I can't have it all.

Comment: @MightyPork You do keep the same method names. Since `ActualStuffTask` is a `PoliteTask`, you can call `before()` on a variable of type `ActualStuffTask`. The call will go through `before()` implemented in `PoliteTask` and invoke `doBefore()` implemented in `ActualStuffTask`.

Comment: Yeah I know, I meant for those that you can implement in the child class. To inherit JavaDoc, for example.

Comment: @MightyPork They already do inherit javadoc. You just can't supply new one (without overriding).

Comment: That's not what I meant, you have some javadoc on `before()`, and then make it final and create `doBefore()`. Extending class has `doBefore()`, but without the JavaDoc which was on `before()`. I'm not sure if there's a way to "include" the javadoc.

Comment: @MightyPork Not as far as I know :(, but you can [`@link` and `@see`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618185/how-can-a-methods-javadoc-be-copied-into-other-methods-javadoc).

Answer (score 3):

The usual approach for such case is like this (simplified example):

```
abstract class Base {

    public final void before() {
        System.out.println("Hey");
        doBefore();
    }

    protected void doBefore() {
    }
}
```

This way base code always will get executed, and subclasses can add their implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).  Create a `final` method in `AbstractClass` (say, `doAll`), that calls the other methods in order:

```
public final void doAll() {
    before();
    doStuff();
    after();
}
```

Then you can have `before` and `after` also be `final` methods, so that they will always be executed by subclasses, and their behavior can't be changed.

Comment: This looks like an interesting pattern, but how is `doAll()` called?

Comment: This `doAll()` method would be called as part of its API.  Normally you would enforce it by making the other methods `protected`, forcing users to call only the `public` method, but you can't do that here because the other methods are defined in the interface and therefore must be `public`.

Comment: Actually now that I thought more about this, I realized it doesn't solve anything, since child classes can't override your final `before()` and `after()`

Answer (score 1):

One option is to call `super.before()` in your `ActualStuffTask` class explicitly:

```
@Override
public void before() {
    super.before();
    // init some things
    fancyNumber = 42;
}
```

Another option is to change design of you parent class and "protect" `before` method with `final` keyword:

```
abstract class PoliteTask implements Task {

    @Override
    public final void before() {
        System.out.println("Hey");
        internalBefore();
    }

    protected abstract void internalBefore(); // child class should override this method

    ...

}
```